# Variable cannot be changed inside Window object

Tags: javascript, cordova

I'm developing a cordova app and within it, I'm using an iFrame. I'm using the following code to communicate between the iFrame and the app itself:

```
var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
var eventer = window[eventMethod];
var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";
var message = "";
var output = "";

eventer(messageEvent, function(e) {
    message = e.data;
    var data = JSON.parse(message);
    for (var i = 0; i < data.messages.length; i++){
        var msg = data.messages[i];
        output = msg.msg;
        alert(output); //*1
    }
}, false);
```

I'm copying the code from here: https://davidwalsh.name/window-iframe

The alert inside the eventer at *1 show the output variable is what I want. But once outside of this eventer function, the variable output reverts to blank.

After some research I think it might because I'm creating a Window object, but I'm not sure if that's the case or exactly what it is.

How can I permenently modify the variable "output"? Thanks.

Comment: *But once outside of this eventer function* What do you mean by that?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 For example, if I add a line at the bottom of that code, like alert(output); the alert will show that the output is blank.

Comment: Ok, so why do you think the output is "blank" if you add a line after that code? Think about what `eventer` does. Hint: It does *not* assign value to `output`.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't really know what the first 3 lines does. If I do an alert(output) before the output = msg.msg line, it **does** shows whatever I have declared outside.

Comment: Also whoever who downvoted, I'd like to know a reason please.

Comment: Ok, first you have to understand that `eventer` only *registers* your callback function. It does not execute it right away. That's why trying to immediately access `output` will only get an undefined value (or in this case, an empty string.) This is how event-based programming works.

Comment: Yes, I got the eventer to execute, and the alert(output) //*1 does shows that the output has the msg. But if that variable is accessed anywhere else, it will show up blank.

Comment: No, the whole point is that `eventer` *does not* execute your callback function in place, and it's not suppose to.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the for loop to this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.messages.length; i++){ 
    var dataMsg = data.messages[i].msg;
    output = dataMsg; alert(output); //*1
 }
```

I don't know if there is an issue with assigning msg.msg to output.

Comment: Doesn't work; the *1 alert is working fine. But that change is not "saved" outside the eventer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your understanding of how events work.

Judging from your comments, this is how you think it works:

```
                                          // Ordering
var output = "";                          // 1. Assign empty string to output
eventer(messageEvent, function(e) {
    // assign value to output             // 2. Assign value to output
});
alert(output);                            // 3. Print output
```

In reality, it works like this:

```
var output = "";                          // 1. Assign empty string to output
eventer(messageEvent, function(e) {
    // assign value to output             // 3. Assign value to output
});
alert(output);                            // 2. Print output
```

The value *is* changed by your callback function, but you are accessing it in the wrong order. `eventer`, or in modern browsers, `.addEventListener`, *registers* a callback function. Your callback function will only get triggered after the current thread is finished. Of course it will print out an empty value, since `alert` is executed before you even changed its value.

If you are not familiar with the basics of event-based programming, I suggest you to take a look at [this tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events).

Just a side note, never use an `iframe` unless you have specific reasons of doing so. And also you do not need the first few lines since you are using Cordova. `attachEvent` is IE-specific.

As a general advice, try not to pollute the global scope with unnecessary variables in the future.

Comment: Sorry I just realised what you were referring to. I should have mention this too. The last alert is triggered via user input via a button. I manually alerted the value of "output" much later after the alert inside the eventer has already triggered. I know and understand the sequence of events in your example, but that's not my issue here. I will modify my question after I get back.